# How to write single (') and (") double quotes to file from a DataFrame?

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, double-quotes, quoting

I am trying to write a DataFrame to file with cells containing single and double quotes. I have used a combination of 'escapechar' and 'quotechar' to achieve it but I have not succeeded:

```
data_test = pd.DataFrame(np.array([["CD's", 'CD\'sss', 1], ['"', '"', 2], ['one', 'other', 3]]))

with open(outfile, 'w') as output_file:     
    writer = csv.writer(output_file,
        delimiter = '\t',
        lineterminator = '\r\n', 
        quotechar = '\'',
        doublequote=False,
        quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, 
        escapechar= '\''
        )
    for i in range(len(data_test)):
        line = data_test.iloc[i]
        writer.writerow(line)      
output_file.close()
```

The output I get contains single double quotes in cells containing single quotes (cell [1,1] and cell [1,2]), but it is not the correct solution.

```
CD''s   CD''sss   1
"       "         2
one     other     3
```

I'm trying to get:

```
CD's    CD'sss    1
"       "         2
one     other     3
```

Any ideas on how to combine single and double quotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this :

```
writer = csv.writer(output_file,
    delimiter = '\t',
    lineterminator = '\r\n',
    quotechar = "\\",
    doublequote=False,
    quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE,
    escapechar="\\"
    )
```

**OUTPUT**

```
CD's    CD'sss  1

"   "   2

one other   3
```

Comment: Great ! @CarlosdelaFuente please accept it as answer

Answer (score 1):

It’s a bit cryptically written, but I think this is the point:

> Dialect.escapechar¶
>   A one-character string used by the writer to escape the delimiter if quoting is set to QUOTE_NONE and the quotechar if doublequote is False. On reading, the escapechar removes any special meaning from the following character. It defaults to None, which disables escaping.

You should set the escape char to None.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be going to a lot of trouble to do something special with your embedded quotation marks.  This does not match your use case.  There *is* no special meaning to them: they are simply characters in the string, to be taken verbatim, just as all the others.  They are data, not command-line strings that might have a special meaning.

Remove your escape handling -- that instructs your writer to *add* those special meanings, and results in the unwanted interpretations.

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't you using `pandas.to_csv`?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv

data_test = pd.DataFrame(np.array([["CD's", 'CD\'sss', 1], ['"', '"', 2], ['one', 'other', 3]]))
data_test.to_csv('out.csv',sep='\t',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE,index=False,header=False)
```

out.csv:

```
CD's    CD'sss  1
"       "       2
one     other   3
```

If line-by-line is needed:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv

data_test = pd.DataFrame(np.array([["CD's", 'CD\'sss', 1], ['"', '"', 2], ['one', 'other', 3]]))

with open('out.csv','w',newline='') as output_file:     
    writer = csv.writer(output_file,delimiter='\t',quotechar='',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    for line in data_test.as_matrix():
        writer.writerow(line)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, works fine! Im not using pandas.to_csv() because I need write line to line that I have a mix of blank lines and filled lines, and in the filled lines I have (,), (") and (\).